# UI Router redirect on form success

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use UI Router in my AngularJS app. When the form is posted I want to load another page.

I've tried the code below. The console.log(data) works fine, but nothing happens with `$state.go('brands')`

There is no error.

```
$http({
...
.success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $state.go('brands');
})
```

UPDATE! Found the **solution**. The form submit was being made in a modal and it did not hide when a new page was loaded:

```
$('#confirm_delete').modal('hide');
$('#confirm_delete').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $state.go("brands");
});
```

Comment: Please show your configuration of your $stateProvider to solve your problem. A better solution is to prepare a jsFiddle to help you in a easier way.

Answer (score 4):

This scenario should be working. There is nothing *against* `UI-Router` states. I've created an example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUKHp5jBH39LSM7yb920?p=preview)

```
// two states
app.config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('main',{
      url: '/',
      templateUrl:"tpl.main.html",
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
    })
    .state('brands',{
      url: '/brands',
      template:"<p> sent.</p>" 
    })    
  }]);
```

And here is a controller, with send action... redirecting to brands state

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state'
  ,function($scope, $http, $state){
    $scope.user = { name : "John" }
    $scope.send = function(){
      $http.get("dummy.json", { params : $scope.user } )
      .success(function(data){
        $state.go("brands");
      })
    }
  }]);
```

Check it and you will see it is working (it uses Get to send model but... the same would apply to POST). Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUKHp5jBH39LSM7yb920?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! This is like my original solution. I found the problem and updated my original post. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow. Good luck with `UI-Router`

Answer (score 0):

You should use $location.url("/brands")

Like This:

```
    angular.module('appName').controller('ThisCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$location',
        function ($scope, $location) {

            $scope.dothis = function(){
                $location.url("/brands");
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Nothing happens I'm afraid.

Comment: are you injecting the $location provider in your controller? please provide the complete controller sample

Comment: I added an example above

Comment: Nothing wrong with your solution, but unfortunately I misunderstood the problem. Updated my original post. Thanks for helping!